# Scheduled data updates in iOS

Tags: ios, background, scheduled-tasks, updates, data-synchronization

I don't know if it is possible to do this in `iOS`: I'd want to be able to call a service to automatically update the data my app needs, let's say, once a day. The problem is that the app could be in inactive state, and I'd not want the user to be required to open the app to request the data update.

I've been told that `Android` has a way to do something like that by configuring in the device an account associated to a certain app, and you can request updates by means of such account. Is there any similar solution for `iOS` apps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using Background Fetch for iOS 7 and above. Check out this tutorial:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/